# Quick sort with vectors strange bugs

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, quicksort

HI, I need help with this function im writing for hw. its not working even though it works fine with arrays instead of vectors. can anyone help please? Thanks in advance :].

```
void quick2 (vector <int> & qlist2, int left, int right) {
    int i = left, j = right;
    int middle = qlist2[qlist2.size()/2];
    if (j - i < 1) {
        return;
    }
    while (i <= j) {
        while (qlist2[i] < middle) {
            i++;
        }
        while (qlist2[j] > middle) {
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j) {
            swap (qlist2[i], qlist2[j]);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }

    if (left < j)
        quick2 (qlist2, left, j);
    if (i < right)
        quick2 (qlist2, i, right);
}
```

Comment: "its not working"  How is it not working?

Comment: j hits -1 in the second `while` loop

Answer (score 3):

Try declaring your function as:

```
void quick2(vector<int> & qlist2, int left, int right)
```

And omitting the `return` statement.

The problem is that arrays are passed by pointer in C and C++.  Each recursive call receives a copy of a pointer to the same block of memory and modifies the same array, allowing the modifications to the array made by the recursive calls to be seen by the caller.

Vectors are objects, so each recursive call is passed a complete copy of the vector.  Any modifications made by the recursive calls are not seen by the caller.  The change above instead passes a *reference* to the vector so that it is not copied for each new function call.  Instead, all the calls operate on the same object.

Also, check your initialization of `middle`.  As written, you're taking the middle element of the array, which will be the same in each call.  (Remember, qlist2.size() isn't going to change from call to call).

Comment: Hey Nick, Thanks for your help :] I realized that I did something really stupid and got the index of the middle instead of the value... haha silly me. I fixed that and changed the function to a void as you suggested but for some reason its looping.